# How can an Admin User save a file as a Standard User

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc, c++17

So I have a program that saves a text file to the C:\ProgramData\MED folder

```
 std::filesystem::path fileName("C:\\ProgramData\\MED\\Data.txt");
 int ret(0);
 FILE *fp;

 ret = _tfopen_s(&fp, fileName.c_str(), _T("w"));
 if (ERROR_SUCCESS == ret)
 {
   _ftprintf_s(fp, _T("1 = Type\n"));
   _ftprintf_s(fp, _T("MED = Name\n"));
   fclose(fp);
 }
```

Now if a Standard User runs the program and creates the Data.txt file, then an Admin User can run the same program and delete that file.

If however an Admin User runs the program and creates the Data.txt file, then a Standard User cannot run the same program and delete that file.  They don't have the correct permissions.

Here is my code for deleting:

```
 for (const auto &entry2 : std::filesystem::directory_iterator("C:\\ProgramData\\MED"))
   std::filesystem::remove_all(entry2.path());
```

So how do I save/create a file that any User can delete or update?

Comment: TL;DR: C++ cannot do that. See [Understanding Windows File And Registry Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/november/access-control-understanding-windows-file-and-registry-permissions) to learn what's lost in C++' `filesystem` abstraction.

Comment: This has got nothing to do with c++. This is a windows permissions problem as mentioned in the comment above. A program written in c# or java would hit the very same wall. Have you considered running the program with specific permissions? Also, have a look at windows services, which is targeted towards solving permissions issues AND background processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remy you are my hero.  It was very easy to modify the SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR.  I added just one line of code:

```
std::filesystem::path fileName("C:\\ProgramData\\MED\\Data.txt");
int ret(0);
FILE *fp;

ret = _tfopen_s(&fp, fileName.c_str(), _T("w"));
if (ERROR_SUCCESS == ret)
{
  _ftprintf_s(fp, _T("1 = Type\n"));
  _ftprintf_s(fp, _T("MED = Name\n"));
  fclose(fp);

  // Now give Standard Users permissions to modify/delete the file
  SetNamedSecurityInfoA("C:\\ProgramData\\MED\\Data.txt", SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: "*an Admin cannot impersonate a Standard User*" - yes, it can. "*save the info out to each users Documents folder*" - you don't need to resort to that, especially if it is going to complicate your configuration. You can instead use the Win32 `CreateFile()` function to create the file, specifying a `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR` that grants access to all users. Or, create the file as you normally would, then use the Win32 `SetFileSecurity()` or `SetNamedSecurityInfo()` function afterwards to change its `SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR`.